# Reading stream data with fetch from nodejs using gfs with react-native

Tags: json, react-native, websocket, fetch, gridfs

[Error: Failed to create Value from JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWqUk.png)

Trying to get a read stream to work from Mongodb (Gridfs) in React-Native Android using fetch.

fetch code:

```
fetch(URL)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err);
```

My readstream on the server is working and sending the data but I cannot for the life of me figure out the appropriate way to handle the data stream.

Code I have tried:

```
response.arrayBuffer()
response.blob()
```

and I keep getting the no value error.

Also, I have tried to push it to an array and the concat the data.

Would websockets be better to use for reading a data stream or can fetch hand the read stream?

Thank you in advanced for taking a look.